# Covariant List interface that allows removal

Tags: c#

In C#, we can't call `Function(IList<Subclass>)` with `IList<Derived>`:

```
class Pet { public string Name { get; set; } }
class Dog : Pet { }
class Cat : Pet { }

static void Remove(IList<Pet> pets, string name) {
    var doomed = pets.FirstOrDefault(pet => pet.Name == name);
    if (doomed != null)
    {
        pets.Remove(doomed);
    }
}

public static void Main() {
    var dogs = new List<Dog> {
        new Dog { Name = "Rover" },
        new Dog { Name = "Spot" },
    };
    Remove(dogs, "Spot"); // illegal
}
```

IList is *invariant*, because you could potentially add a `Cat` to a `List<Dog>`, which is obviously bad.

But in this case, all I want to do is *remove* items from the List. This poses no threat to the integrity of the List.

I know that `IReadOnlyList` exists which gives you a covariant "view" of a List. Is there something like `ICovariantList` that gives you covariant-friendly methods of List, including the `Remove` method? If not, does anyone know why?

---

EDIT: In response to comments, the following code is more representative of my actual app, but we have to imagine that it's less easy to rearrange. We have *many* list of `Dogs` and `Cats` and other `Pet` subclasses, which are aggregate together via something like `GetPetLists`, which an enumeration of Pet lists that we wish to operate on.

If we just wanted to *view* these lists, we could use `IReadOnlyView`. But we want to remove an item from one of the lists:

```
class Pet { public string Name { get; set; } }
class Dog : Pet { }
class Cat : Pet { }

List<Dog> dogs = new List<Dog> {
    new Dog { Name = "Rover" },
    new Dog { Name = "Spot" },
};

List<Cat> cats = new List<Cat> {
    new Cat { Name = "Snowball" },
    new Cat { Name = "Fluffy" },
};

// IEnumerable<IReadOnlyList<Pet>> GetPetLists() // legal, but not what we need
// IEnumerable<ICovariantList<Pet>> GetPetList() // what I'm looking for; allows Remove
IEnumerable<IList<Pet>> GetPetLists() // illegal, for good reason
{
    yield return dogs;
    yield return cats;
}

void RemovePet(string name)
{
    foreach (var list in GetPetLists())
    {
        var doomed = list.FirstOrDefault(pet => pet.Name == name);
        if (doomed != null)
        {
            list.Remove(doomed);
        }
    }
}

void Test()
{
    RemovePet("Spot"); 
}
```

Comment: _"does anyone know why?"_ - I'm not on the .NET team so I can't speak authoritatively, but the team that manages the .NET Collections library is very risk-averse, not just to breaking-changes, but also avoids adding new types because of the increased _forever maintenance_ burden that would introduce.

Comment: Anyway, for a quick-fix, `delegate` types in C# support covariance and contravariance, so you could use a separate parameter to pass-in a delegate to a `Remove` method.

Comment: BTW, I know your posted code is just a toy-example, but using `FirstOrDefault` is bad for runtime complexity because you're doing `O(n) + O(n)` - and `Remove` won't throw if its argument is not a member of the collection: instead it returns `true`/`false` if the element was found-and-removed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1.remove?view=net-7.0

Comment: I mentioned it because I wasn't sure if my remarks about your use of `FirstOrDefault` are valid or not - so my reply was framed for the context - and that was because you didn't disclose what your **actual** use-case is, which is bad-form on SO because that's how people get into X/Y Problem arguments.

Comment: Are you opposed to this method signature: `static void Remove<T>(IList<T> pets, string name) where T : Pet`?

Comment: @moreON I added a code exactly that's more representative of my actual app. This is in a large commercial code base. There dozens of different "Pet" lists, all various subclasses, that are aggregated via an iterator. I want to perform an operation on those lists. As long as I don't want to do *any* manipulation to the lists, I could have the iterator return an enumeration of `IReadOnlyList<Pet>`. But I want to remove an item from the lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could make the parameter an `IEnumerable<Pet>` which is covariant since C#4 (because you cannot modify it directly), then you can try-cast it to `IList` and then use the `Remove` method:

```
static void Remove(IEnumerable<Pet> pets, string name) {
    var doomed = pets.FirstOrDefault(pet => pet.Name == name);
    if (doomed != null)
    {
        if(pets is IList list && !list.IsReadOnly) 
        {
            list.Remove(doomed);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't work, as far as I can tell. `IList` requires a type parameter. I'd want to make that `IList<Pet>`, but `is` won't evaluate as true for `IList<Pet>` if I pass in `IList<Dog>`.

Comment: @Mud `System.Collections.IList` and `System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>` are distinct types, this answer appears to be using the former. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist?view=net-7.0 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ilist-1?view=net-7.0

Comment: Right you are! Bit of a hack, but it works. Thanks. :)

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gxC7d8

Would prefer if the `Pets` property could return something like `ICovariantList`, which included only methods that wouldn't break type invariance, which at the very least is everything in `IReadOnlyList` and the `IList.Remove()` method. Alas.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you get around your issue by simply and solely changing the signature of `Remove` from `void Remove(IList<Pet> pets, string name)` to `void Remove<P>(IList<P> pets, string name) where P : Pet`.

This now works:

```
class Pet { public string Name { get; set; } }
class Dog : Pet { }
class Cat : Pet { }

static void Remove<P>(IList<P> pets, string name) where P : Pet
{
    var doomed = pets.FirstOrDefault(pet => pet.Name == name);
    if (doomed != null)
    {
        pets.Remove(doomed);
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    var dogs = new List<Dog> {
        new Dog { Name = "Rover" },
        new Dog { Name = "Spot" },
    };
    Remove(dogs, "Spot"); // Now Legal without any change to this code.
}
```

---

Your edit effectively changes your question to how to make this illegal code legal:

```
IEnumerable<IList<Pet>> GetPetLists() // illegal, for good reason
{
    yield return dogs;
    yield return cats;
}
```

This cannot be legal, so it now makes the rest of your code moot. It therefore cannot be a better representation of your actual code. Can you give us something that does represent your code?

Comment: **"This cannot be legal"** It can if you change `IList<Pet>` to `IEnumerable<Pet>` or `IReadOnly<Pet>`. The question is if there was an equivalent covariant interface that also allows `Remove()`, as that method doesn't violate type invariance.